# VueJS won't display data from Express API

Tags: express, vue.js

I have a vue component that makes this call for search results:

```
    async searchGroups() {
        this.searching = true;
        console.log('going to group service search...')
  let response = await GroupsService.searchGroups({
            terms: this.terms
        })
        this.results = response;
        console.log('this is search results: ', response);
        this.terms = '';
  this.searching = false;
},
```

this is the code in GroupsService:

```
async searchGroups (params) {
    await axios.get('groups/search?text=' + params.terms)
  }
```

I can see in Network tab of Chrome console  that the search for "library" returns:

```
[{id: 6, name: "An Old Group",…},…]
0: {id: 6, name: "An Old Group",…}
1: {id: 9, name: "one more for the first user", description: "south oran library "}
```

but response returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async searchGroups (params) {
   await axios.get('groups/search?text=' + params.terms)
}
```

you are not returning anything from this function ?!

Try to return the result of this async function (searchGroups)

```
async searchGroups (params) {
  return await axios.get('groups/search?text=' + params.terms)
}
```

Comment: the axios call is returning data that I can see in the Chrome browser dev tools network tab. but for some reason, I can't get that data to show up in the vue component

Comment: The axios call is returning data but you are retuning nothing from the searchGroups function, you have to add "return in front of the await" see my answer

Comment: can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much!